# Problems to use layout grid() and pack() in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, layout, tkinter

I do not understand how to use the grid() function and the pack() in Python Tkinter. I've seen a tutorial but I can not sort the items I want. I'm using the pack function, but I don't know if grid function is better... I also want that the widgets are  flexible depending on size of screen. The app is designed for a 7" screen (tactil screen of Raspberry pi) but maybe it will work on another screen... 
I attached a link with the layout that I would prefer, I hope somebody can help me! Thanks!!

[Layout image](https://www.dropbox.com/s/lzc0l95bjqtcpbz/tkinter_pack.jpg?dl=0)

```
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import *
import time

TITLE_FONT= ("Verdana", 18)
TEXT_FONT = ("Verdana", 14)
QUESTION_FONT = ("Verdana", 14)
today = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y")


class Interface(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        container = tk.Frame(self)

        #container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid()

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)


        self.frames = {}

        for F in (MenuInici, Page2, Page3):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


        self.show_frame(MenuInici)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class MenuInici(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)


        self.label1 = tk.Label(self, text="PAGE1", font=TITLE_FONT,bg="green", fg="black")
        self.label2 = tk.Label(self, text=today, font=TITLE_FONT,bg="blue", fg="black") 

        self.label1.pack(side = TOP, expand =TRUE)
        self.label2.pack(side = TOP)

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Button1(none)", width=15, height=3, 
                            command=self.Iniciar)
        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Button2(page2)",width=15, height=3,
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page2))
        button3 = tk.Button(self, text="Button3(quit)",width=15, height=3,
                            command=self.quit)
        button4 = tk.Button(self, text="Button4(quit)",width=15, height=3,
                            command=self.quit)
        button5 = tk.Button(self, text="Button5",width=15, height=3,
                            command=self.quit)
        button6 = tk.Button(self, text="Button6(quit)",width=15, height=3,
                            command=self.quit)

        button1.pack(side = TOP,pady=6)
        button2.pack(side = TOP,pady=6)
        button3.pack(side = TOP,pady=6)
        button4.pack(side = RIGHT,pady=6)
        button5.pack(side = RIGHT,pady=6)
        button6.pack(side = RIGHT,pady=6)



    def Iniciar(self,var):
        pass 


    def quit(self):
        app.destroy()


class Page2(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Page2", font=TITLE_FONT).pack()
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text=today, font=TITLE_FONT).pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Page3",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(Page3)).pack()


        button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MenuInici))
        button2.pack()




class Page3(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label1 = tk.Label(self, text="Page3", font=TITLE_FONT)
        label2 = tk.Label(self, text=today, font=TITLE_FONT)

        label1.pack()
        label2.pack()

        button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back",
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(MenuInici)).pack()



app = Interface()
w,h = app.maxsize()
app.geometry("%dx%d"%(630,360))
app.title ("Hello")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: 1. You cannot use pack and grid in one window.
2. Use columspan, expand instructions

Read this manual (http://zetcode.com/gui/tkinter/layout/) look at last example.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using `grid` on a widget, you have to use a `pack` on it before. For an example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("Test: Pack and Grid")
label = Label(root)
label.pack() # Pack Command: Show my widget 'label' on the screen.
label.grid(row=0, column=0) # Grid Command: I want my widget 'label' to be on the first(0) row and on the first column(0)
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. If you call `pack()` and then call `grid()`, the effects of `pack()` are ignored. Calling pack in such a situation is completely pointless.